# How are different HTML elements equivalent?

Tags: html

Some HTML elements (`<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, ..., `<h6>` `<b>`, `<i>`, and so on) seem to behave the same way except for default styling. For example, `<span style="font-weight: bold;"> x </span>` seems equivalent to `<b> x </b>`. Some elements such as `<a>` have special properties but behave mostly the same way.

Can someone make this precise?

In particular, is there a subset of elements that "covers" all of HTML?

---

**Edit:** I understand that elements are meant to carry semantics. But suppose that I don't care about semantics, and I only want to deal with the smallest subset of HTML that will give me access to some given *browser behavior*. I'm wondering how to find that subset.

Comment: Maybe you want to read the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/ `<b>` is deprecated or at least discouraged in HTML4.

Comment: Why not? There [you can find useful information](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2), such as *"The following HTML elements specify font information. Although they are not all deprecated, their use is discouraged in favor of style sheets."* To be honest, I don't really understand what kind of answer you expect. HTML is about semantics, not style (that's why some elements are deprecated now). Each element has a distinct meaning.

Comment: This question is interesting to me. Unless it's a duplicate, I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @Felix - I'm asking about the behavior of elements, not their meaning. The spec doesn't give a clean answer, I was hoping not to have to wade through it myself. (Sorry I deleted my snarky comment before you replied.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *behaviour*? In what sense? It's not that the tags are *doing* anything. HTML is a markup language, so the markup provides additional *information*, but not *behaviour*.

Comment: I mean browser behavior. Displaying bolded text, for instance.

Comment: How the browser interprets and display certain tags is implementation depended. E.g. the spec also says *"Rendering of font style elements depends on the user agent. The following is an informative description only."*

Comment: @FelixKling Actually, in HTML5, [`b` is not deprecated at all](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-b-element.html#the-b-element); in fact, it serves a useful purpose. So are so-called "presentational tags" like [`i`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-i-element.html#the-i-element), [`u`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-u-element.html#the-u-element), and [`s`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-s-element.html#the-s-element).

Comment: @mc10: Yes, I also had a closer look at the HTML4 spec and it seems their use is just discourage but they are not deprecated. Well, I freely repeated the text in the specification ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some reasons why an element cannot fully be replicated by `<span class="...">` ignoring mere semantics and just considering browser or other HTML consumer behaviour:

- The element is [the root element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-html-element.html#the-html-element).
- The element is [a metadata element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-html-element.html#document-metadata)
- The element is [a scripting element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/scripting-1.html#scripting-1)
- The element is [an embedded content element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/embedded-content-1.html#embedded-content-1)
- The element is [a forms element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#forms)
- The element is [an interactive element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/interactive-elements.html#interactive-elements)
- The element is [a links element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/links.html#links)
- The element is used by [the document outline algorithm](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/headings-and-sections.html#outlines); including:

  - [Sectioning content elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#sectioning-content)
  - [Sectioning root elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/headings-and-sections.html#sectioning-root)
  - [Heading content elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#heading-content)
- The element goes in a place in the DOM where [a span is precluded from going by the parser](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tabular-data.html#tabular-data)
- The element forms part of [a specific rendering binding](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/rendering.html#bindings)
- The element has [a default WAI-ARIA role other than 'no role'](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/wai-aria.html#wai-aria)
- The element's [DOM interface extends beyond that of HTMLElement](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#htmlelement)
- The element is the `span` element itself.

By my reckoning that leaves `abbr`, `address`, `b`, `bdi`, `bdo`, `br`, `cite`, `code`, `dd`, `dfn`, `div`, `dl`, `dt`, `em`, `footer`, `header`, `kbd`, `mark`, `p`, `pre`, `rp`, `rt`, `ruby`, `s`, `samp`, `strong`, `sub`, `sup`, `u`, `var` and `wbr` as the **maximum** list of elements replaceable by span if one ignores semantics. That's 31 out of 107 different elements in HTML5. Of the other 76, each has a specific job in browsers.

I note that of the above list, there are a number where I don't know what the equivalent styling would be, and that in all cases it's less typing to use the correct semantic element than to replace it with a span+class.

Answer (score 6):

HTML is meant to mark up text ***semantically***. That means giving *meaning* to a piece of text, like *this is a headline*, *this is a paragraph*, *this is a quote*, *this should be emphasized*. Some/most of them are displayed very similar by default, but that's not the point. The point is to be able to programmatically extract *meaning* and process elements according to their meaning, for example by styling them. Don't confuse *semantics* with *style*.

If you want to leave that aside, you pretty much only need block level elements like a `div` and inline elements like `span`, plus anything that has a specific function like links, objects etc.

Comment: I understand that elements are meant to carry semantics. But suppose that I don't care about semantics, and I only want to deal with the smallest subset of HTML that will give me access to some given *browser behavior*. I'm wondering how to find that subset.

Comment: Virtually all browser behaviour can be achieved just with `<span>` tags and CSS. There are very few exceptions. If you add javascript to the mix, then there are almost no exceptions - you can do anything with just `<span>`. But web pages are parsed by many things other than browsers (search engines, screen readers for visually impaired, etc) and so you *really* should care about semantics. One of the recommendations from the guys who created HTML, is your page should be perfectly functional with all the CSS and JavaScript removed.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you mean by browser behavior. All browsers will treat e.g. `a` elements with `href` attributes in a special way, as links, and this cannot be expressed in CSS. Similarly, form input fields are special, and so is `img`, even though you can simulate much of its behavior by using a background image in CSS. But what about `abbr` for example? Although most browsers just apply some default styling to it, some special browsers or assistive tools used with them give the user optional access to the value of the `title` attribute. Similarly, while most browsers treat `h1` and other heading elements just by applying some default styling to them, some browsers have e.g. a mode where the browser only reads the headings to the user.

Similarly, you can create tables using CSS (`display: table` etc.) without using any table markup in HTML—though older browsers won’t get this right—but then your “tables” will not have accessibility features that HTML tables can have.

Search engines are not browsers, but they may be very important, and they are known to pay attention to HTML markup, though the details have not been disclosed. However, if you start e.g. using styled `div` elements intead of heading elements, you will probably lose something in search engine friendlyness.

Comment: Actually, this "browsers treat `a` elements with `href` attributes in a special way, as links, and this cannot be expressed in CSS" isn't quite true. If you had a span you *could* use CSS to style it like a link with the changed mouse-pointer and use the attribute `onClick="window.location="example.com"`. **This is a very bad idea**, but totally possible.

Answer (score 1):

Some elements have a very specific purpose, for example `html`, `head`, `body`, `script`, `meta`, `embed`, `object`, `hr`, `table`, `tr`, `td`, `form`, `input`. They do things that isn't possible to do by just specifying a style.

The rest of the elements, for example `span`, `div`, `b`, `i`, `u`, `h1`, `p`, only differ in their default style. You can use a `span` tag and apply `display:block` to it, and it works as a `div` tag.

Note though that there are block elements like `div`, and there are inline elements like `span`. You can't put a block element inside an inline element (until all browsers support HTML 5).

So, you strictly don't need all different elements. Some elements are even deprecated in HTML 4, for example `b` and `i`, as they are not needed and doesn't follow modern markup usage, so they should be replaced by styling.

You should however consider the semantics that the different elements add. The `h1` element for example is important for search engines when they try to find out what the page is about. If you don't use the `h1` element for your headline, search engines will rate your page lower.

Comment: I think `hr`, `table`, `tr` and `td` can all be replicated with CSS. At least in some browsers. You'd be crazy to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between them is semantic. To illustrate, in HTML5 for example, you have div, section, header, footer etc., which are all block elements. In HTML4 you're required to use div for all of those. Which is easier to read, to look at, to style - a page full of div's or something divided into headers, and sections, and footers?

As you state, some elements have attributes that are specific to that element type/or certain types (e.g., a). So there's another difference.

Finally, in your list, you also have some block level (e.g., div, p) and some inline level (e.g., span, b) elements - those have very different default behaviors. See: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Comment: ...and what Guffa said... ;-)